# Apache simple global filter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi All :) I setup a simple test Apache server, and need to write a filter for it, a global one, a filter which forwards all, ALL, page requests to the local /index.html, *BUT* only serves normally the following files when requested:
- of course /index.html
- /page.php
- all /*.css or /*.js

I tried lots of combinations in file .htaccess, but none do the thing.. the best I got is for example the following:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule !^(index.html)|^(page.php)|.(js|css)$ /index.html

.. but it doesnt work, and it serves only the first level files, I mean /xxx, but not the /xxx/yyy or /xxx/yyy/zzz, etc.. I need the filter working on all directory levels.
.. what Im doing wrong? maybe any other setup file to update? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(page\.php|index\.html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.